# How to Properly Convert List to JavaScript Array?

Tags: jquery, jinja2

I tried to call an Jquery [Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) that source of auto complete option is from a list below

```
{% set Source = ['Customer', 'Name', 'Salutation', 'First Name English', '[Type Item Here]'] %}
```

Because Jquery AutoComplete accept an array, I tried to find a way to convert my list into a javascript array, but no result success.

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="ui-widget">
        <label>Tags: </label>
        <input class="tags">
      </div>
    </div>

    {% set Source = ['Customer', 'Name', 'Salutation', 'First Name English', '[Type Item Here]'] %}

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

        /* Auto Complete Form Label*/
        var availableTags = "{{Source|safe}}";

            // alert('auto');
            $( ".tags" ).autocomplete({
              source: availableTags,
              autoFocus: true,
              minLength: 1
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Therefore, how can I properly convert my list `Source` into a javascript array to that my AutoComplete will also work as well? Thanks

Comment: convert to json and print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert it into JSON and then print, use [`tojson` filter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/templating/#standard-filters) for that. Since `JSON` is valid javascript there is no need for additional parsing or quotes wrapping.

```
<script>

    // .....

    var tagsList = {{ autocompletList|tojson|safe }};
    var availableTags = {{ Source|tojson|safe }};

    // ..... 

<script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, a moment  I followed that with double quote " " and I got an internal server error 500, that server always route to url that rendering this jinja template, until I backed to your answer again and removed double quote, thanks so much your help, now it's working correctly :)